# SQL "for" in select: smarter way?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know if there is an effective way in (My)SQL to do a select statement that resembles a for-loop in most programming languages. The simplest example would be to create a column with the values of 1 to 100. I have searched for solutions around (the one I found most interesting was one with cross joining each digit up to target length). In the end, I created a table named N (as in the maths symbol) in my db witha single column 'n' and values from 1 to 1 million.

Here's an example I've needed this:

```
select .....
cross join
(
select n,str_to_date(period_add(date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y%m'),n),'%Y%m') as 'date' from n where  n<period_diff(201912,date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y%m'))
)
```

This returns a column with all the year/month combinations from curdate (happens to be march 2017) to Dec 2019. You can see the n used as a "variable" to add months and to calculate the "for loop's end condition". This works well. The question then is: is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Your method is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine.  I might be inclined to do:

```
select date_add(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day), interval n.n month)
from n
where date_add(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day), interval n.n month) <= '2019-12-01'
```

I prefer doing date arithmetic rather than going back and forth to strings.

The expression:

```
date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day)
```

is just a way of getting the first day of the month.